# Android Studio set alignment of part of a String to the right in a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, alignment, spannablestring

I have a listview with an Arraylistadapter and want to set parts of the String in the listview to the right.

[image: right now it looks like this]

```
    ListView Names = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewAssetsNames);


    String Peter = "Peter";
    String PeterNumber = "12345";

    int Namelength = Peter.length();
    int Numberlength = PetersNumber.length() + Namelength +1 ;
    final SpannableStringBuilder Peterfinal = new SpannableStringBuilder(Peter + " " + PetersNumber);
    Peterfinal.setSpan((new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE)), Namelength, Numberlength, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    SpannableStringBuilder[] TestStrings = new SpannableStringBuilder[1];


    TestStrings [0] = Peterfinal;
    ArrayAdapter<SpannableStringBuilder> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<SpannableStringBuilder>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            TestStrings

    );


    Names.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

}
```

[image: how it should look like]

I've tried to use Spannable String and set the Alignment of the number part of the String to the right which leads to setting the whole String to the right.

It's important that it is one listview. I already experimented with using 2 listview set beside but then ther is the problem with scrolling one listview the other doesnt go with the scrolling.

Comment: try for a custom layout

Comment: Create cutomArrayAdapter use following link for reference: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: Take two text views  left and right align.

Comment: @Nisatru Check answer and give feedback

Comment: Ok so with help from Jason Bourne's answer I created a custom layout with 2 Textviews. So my problem now is: How can I set which TextView is getting which String? [link](https://ibb.co/d2Ke6F)

Comment: @Nisatru buddy, you wont get your listview items in there. 
You have to write a custom adapter class for that.

Comment: Answer updated. please check.

Comment: @Nisatru did you do any checking?

Comment: @JasonBourne Hey I got it working. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Nisatru welcolme buddy, dont forget to ask help next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a custom List item Like this: 
**listview_item_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

<TextView
    android:text="Peter"
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

<TextView
    android:text="12345"
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It will give you desired output:

[image]

And in here set the custom layout Adapter:

```
MyAdapter.java 
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyData>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    MyData data[] = null;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Mydata[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new WeatherHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        MyData data = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle1.setText(data.title);
        holder.txtTitle2.setText(data.icon);

        return row;
    }

    static class WeatherHolder
    {
        TextView txtTitle1;
        TextView txtTitle2;
    }
}
```

In the data class:

```
public class MyData {
    public String icon;
    public String title;
    public MyData(){
        super();
    }

    public MyData(String icon, String title) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Then in the Activity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listView1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MyData my_data[] = new MyData[]
        {
            new Weather("Peter", "12345"),
           };

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.listview_item_row, my_data);


        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
        listView1.addHeaderView(header);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Ok so I made the custom layout and set it in the listviewadapter. When trying to run it it says that it need a ressource ID for the textviews. How do i do that. Sorry for that probably fun question but I'm new to android programming and especially listviews and arrayadapters

Comment: @Nisatru follow everything here http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Just change listview_item_row.xml  with my xml code